# How to encode URL in JavaScript and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, url, urlencode, decode

I want to send a URL in a POST request in a variable called `surl`. How should I encode it in JavaScript and decode it in PHP? For example, the value of `surl` could be `http://www.google.co.in/search?q=javascript+urlencode+w3schools`.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot to mention, it's not form submission but a ajax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent(uri)` (for encoding) and `decodeURIComponent(uri)` for decoding,

E.g (encoding).

```
var uri="http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
document.write(encodeURIComponent(uri));
```

Output

> http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab

Decoding is left for the reader. :-)

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to to anything. Send it as is. Browser and PHP will do all escaping and unescaping for you (if you use `form.surl.value = surl; form.submit()` and `$_POST['surl']`). Or you can just use the plain form without any JavaScript (if it fulfills your needs).

**Replying henasraf's comment.**  Try this.

```
<form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"
    onsubmit="this.via_js.value=this.via_plain_form.value;">
<input type="hidden" name="via_js"/>
<input type="text" name="via_plain_form" value="Paste you url here"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    var_export($_POST);
}

?>
```

For `http://www.google.co.in/search?q=javascript+urlencode+w3schools`, it outputs

```
array (
    'via_js' => 'http://www.google.co.in/search?q=javascript+urlencode+w3schools',
    'via_plain_form' => 'http://www.google.co.in/search?q=javascript+urlencode+w3schools',
    'submit' => 'Submit',
)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but + in the URL would count as space, no? PHP wouldn't fix it I'm sure, it *will* fix regular spaces and turn them to "+" signs and vice-versa, but to add a literal + you'd have to use `%2B`. I think this applies in other cases too.

Comment: PHP or browser don't care if you transmit URL or something else. URL is treated like any other form data. Browser escapes all fancy characters in your form data, transmits data, and PHP unescapes them on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

As for PHP, it's `urlencode()` and `urldecode()`.