# add javascript variable to href

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I currently have this

```
destDiv.append("<td><a href="+value.FileLocation+">Download Here</a></td>")
```

But I actually want to url encode the value.filelocation to my download script getsonginfo.php

Comment: So use `encodeURIComponent` and encode it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Here comes the answer train. Did you try researching "url encode value javascript"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode URL in JavaScript and PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332413/how-to-encode-url-in-javascript-and-php)

Comment: Thanks for all the sarcasm, its really helpful. of course i researched, struggled for an hour then asked a question. :D

Comment: It wasn't sarcastic, it was a question. I typed the exact phrase above into Stack Overflow search and found an answer, so I wondered if you had tried that.

Comment: here comes the answer train. sounds sarcastic to me..I could have been wrong :)

Comment: Oh, that? In reference to the fact that easy questions that are duplicated frequently attract a ton of answers from lower-rep users tying to build up. Understandable, but ultimately not very useful for cleaning up duplicates. It rewards people who post questions that didn't (it appears) do research or note the possible duplicates shown as they posted the question. Since they got their answer, people trying to keep things clean look like jerks for voting to close ("But I got an answer, this question is good!") Frequent topic of conversation on Meta, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, all you want to do is the following:

```
destDiv.append("<td><a href='getsonginfo.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(value.FileLocation)+"'>Download Here</a></td>")
```

The `encodeURIComponent` will handle encoding the `value.FileLocation` correctly, and the href needs a `'` around it so that it's properly parsed (otherwise the `encodeURIComponent` is pointless).

Comment: Where'd you get `getsonginfo.php?url=` from? 0_o

Comment: And, where did you get the idea that it needs a single quote around it? Not true.

Comment: @DJDavid98 "to my download script getsonginfo.php" the `url=` part was improvisation on my part, but working in PHP that's the most likely construction.

Comment: @Chris Either single or double quote, but without it certain strings will get encoded incorrectly which actually is only relevant if the `FileLocation` can contain user content.

Comment: The statement is simply incorrect. The function call to encodeURIComponent is not aware of the context it is being called from. It doesn't know if you're concatenating it into a string, setting it as a element property, logging to console... it doesn't know or care. It does what it does, using a single quote in your HTML does not impact that in the slightest.

Comment: thank you. the result is
<a href="getsonginfo.php?url=private%2FXmasPrisonBlues.wma">Download Here</a>